# My App keeps taking me back to signup page even after it checks if the user is logged in

Tags: android, firebase

I have added the splash screen to launch every time the app starts or even gets killed , then splash screen checks for the user if is logged in but unfortunately it directs me to the mainactivity but then later if takes me back to signup page after some couple of seconds and am not getting any error what am i missing here fellaz thanks alot

**Hereis my Manifest**

````
```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.signuppage"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.LoginScreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.MainActivityCenterofInformation"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.MainActivityAEA"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.MainActivitySNAL"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.MainActivityBvm"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.MainActivityForest"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.MainActivitySocial"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.MainActivityCollegeofAgriculture"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.IntroActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.WelcomeScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>```
````

**Here is my welcomescreen as the splash screen**

````
```package com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.data.model.User;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.univibezstudios.ocappservice.ocapp.WelcomeScreen;

public class WelcomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView logo;



    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setFullscreen ();
        setContentView (R.layout.welcomescreen);


        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance ();
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser ();


        if(firebaseUser != null)
        {
            startActivity (new Intent (WelcomeScreen.this
                    , MainActivity.class));
        }


        logo= findViewById (R.id.logoocaap);

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (this,R.anim.splashscreen);
        logo.startAnimation (animation);



       new Handler ().postDelayed (new Runnable () {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               Intent intent = new Intent (WelcomeScreen.this,IntroActivity.class);
               startActivity (intent);
               finish ();
           }
       },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }








    private void setFullscreen(){

        requestWindowFeature (Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    }
}```
````

Comment: Where is the code of `MainActivity`?. I think there is no code to start SignUp page here.

Comment: @ShylendraMadda didn't get you there bro

Comment: have updated the question and added the mainaactivity class

Comment: You can check **[this](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebaseauthapp/splash)** out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Handler is still running after going to MainActivity and it triggers Introactivity. .There are many ways to do it but my suggestion would be to add your Firebase's user checking condition in Handler.

Remove the firebase's user check from above and put it in Handler's run method.

```
new Handler ().postDelayed (new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(firebaseUser != null) {
                startActivity (new Intent (WelcomeScreen.this
                        , MainActivity.class));
                finish ();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent (WelcomeScreen.this,IntroActivity.class);
                startActivity (intent);
                finish ();
            }
        }
    },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

Comment: Kayla if this answer solves your issue, mark it as the accepted answer. so other future folks can get benefits from it.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in else condition of firebase user != Null

```
new Handler ().postDelayed (new Runnable () { @Override public void run() { Intent intent = new Intent (WelcomeScreen.this,IntroActivity.class); startActivity (intent); finish (); } },SPLASH_TIME_OUT)
```